# Google+: How do I retrieve "How many times I posted this month"

Tags: jquery, google-plus

I want to retrieve how may posts I've posted with in 30 days using Google+ API and jQuery.  How do I approach this? I couldn't find the parameter for date range in the api document.

Here is what I have so far with json
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/+BarackObama/activities/public?maxResults=100&fields=items(id%2Cupdated)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I basically want to display something like "I posted XX post in Google+ this month".

Comment: Posting moths is a bad idea, you'll just end up with bugs in your mail sender.

Answer (score 0):

They only way to accomplish this is to paginate back through all activities posted by a user and count the total within your code. Of course you can keep a cache of the total or the activities locally so that you only have to do this once a day or so.